# Buffer position is invalid

Tags: java, file

My program should write doubles to the file. The result should be a file with 1,000,000,000 doubles. But for some reason, the error crashes when the file becomes 2 gigabytes this is approximately 250,000 doubles.

At the same time, she perfectly creates a file with 10 000 000 and 100 000 000 doubles
Why it happens ?

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Random;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
public class writeFileMapped {
    public static final int BUF_SIZE = 10000 * Double.BYTES;
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Random random = new Random();
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Den\\IdeaProjects\\semester_3\\src\\File_task\\test3.dat");
        try (FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(path, CREATE, WRITE, READ)) {
            long startBubbleTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                MappedByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, i * BUF_SIZE, BUF_SIZE);
                while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
                    double d = random.nextDouble();
                    buf.putDouble(d);
                }
                channel.read(buf);
            }
            long endBubbleTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(endBubbleTime-startBubbleTime);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative position
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:942)
    at File_task.writeFileMapped.main(writeFileMapped.java:18)
```

18 strings = MappedByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, i * BUF_SIZE, BUF_SIZE);

Comment: Your numbers are a bit confusing - you say it's okay with 10,000,000 or 100,000,000 but it fails with 250,000 doubles. Did you mean it fails with 250,000,000 doubles?

Comment: I strongly suspect that `i * BUF_SIZE` is overflowing, btw.

Comment: I think I have it figured out, Doing some tests right now before posting the answer :)

Comment: Yep figured it out! posting the answer now

Comment: This is the problem, 10 000 000 doubles and 100 000 000 it puts, and when trying to create 1 000 000 000 gives an error of 250 000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I debugged, Your position is crashing in `-2147447296` which means It's the max value of integer, Just change your ints to longs

```
public static final long BUF_SIZE = 10000 * Double.BYTES;

for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
```

How ever you might also want to cast it to long when you multiply the position, I have got the file to 4GB and then stopped the program